# How to enable select all feature in material-ui/SelectField component?

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, multi-select

[Document Link](https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field)
I am following the above document Link for implementing the Select-field component.
I didnot find the proper document for select all in this component.

Import statement for component

```
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
```

Component code:

```
<SelectField
    className="search_items"
    multiple={true}
    hintText="Select Item"
    value={values}
    onChange={this.handleChange} >
    {this.menuItems(values)}
 </SelectField>
```

menuItems Function:

```
menuItems(values) {
     return unique && unique.map((name) => (
        <MenuItem
            key={name}
            insetChildren={true}
            checked={values && values.indexOf(name) > -1}
            value={name}
            primaryText={name && name.concat('(').concat(sectors.filter(i => i === name).length).concat(')')}
        />
    ));
}
```

OnChange Function :

```
handleChange(event, index, values) {
    this.setState({ values })
}
```

How to enable select all option for all the items to be selected.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `MenuItem` above all the choices.

```html
<SelectField
        multiple={true}
        hintText="Multiple Select"
        value={values}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      >
          <MenuItem
            checked={this.state.open}
            value="Select all"
            onClick={this.selectAll}
            primaryText={checkedAll?"Select None":"Select all"}
          />
        {this.menuItems(values)}
      </SelectField>
```

Create a state `checkedAll` which is updated whenever the `Select All` item is clicked. Whenever the `SelectAll` MenuItem is clicked update the values to the required data(here unique) using a function.

```js
selectAll = () => {
    if(this.state.checkedAll)
      this.setState(
        {values:[]}
      );
    else
      this.setState(
        {values:names}
      );
    this.setState({
      checkedAll:!this.state.checkedAll
    });
  }
```

Comment: For the first time from the values when i click on select All, All the items are not getting selected showing selected none with selected, then second time all are getting selected

Comment: in selectAll function it should be 
if(!this.state.checkedall) in first line?
It would work right if this is the case

Comment: Material UI - `MenuItem` component doesn't support events including `onClick` as of today (2019-12-12) thus this solution doesn't work. 

I found that the `ListItemText` has an `onClick` event which can be nested into the `MenuItem` component - as shown at https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#multiple-select - "tag" menu. 
Although, for some reason, combining it with the `Select` component's `onChange` event caused it behaving funny and couldn't trigger any hooks from the onClick's handle.

Answer (score 14):

Create a `Select` with `multiple` property and an option `Select All` along with other options.

Like with the single selection, you can pull out the new value by accessing `event.target.value` in the `onChange` callback. It's always an array. When `Select All` is clicked, the value `all` (in this example) will be present in the last index of the array which can be used to toggle select all or unselect all options.

**This example has a checkbox prefixed in the options.*

Here's the link to the [working demo in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-multiple-select-with-select-all-option-givp5?file=/src/App.js).

```js
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

const handleChange = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  if (value[value.length - 1] === "all") {
    setSelected(selected.length === options.length ? [] : options);
    return;
  }
  setSelected(value);
};
```

```jsx
<Select
  multiple
  value={selected}
  onChange={handleChange}
  renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
>
  <MenuItem value="all">
    <ListItemIcon>
      <Checkbox
        checked={options.length > 0 && selected.length === options.length}
        indeterminate={selected.length > 0 && selected.length < options.length}
      />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Select All" />
  </MenuItem>
  {options.map((option) => (
    <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <Checkbox checked={selected.indexOf(option) > -1} />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={option} />
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>
```

Comment: This solution is working perfectly in my case

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make the accepted answer work well. So please refer to the answer of anonymous_siva before reading this.

So yes, you can't make the  component handle events without unpleasant side effects. But you can remove event handling from  to a child with an event like this:

```js
<MenuItem key={'Select all'}>
  <ListItemText
    primary="Select all"
    onClick={(event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();
      setValues(values);
    }}
  />
</MenuItem>
```

Here you can see that we need to stop propagation and update your component's state with all default options that are available.

You can do exactly the same for deselect all option, but change state to being empty.

Now, you need to manually override margins and paddings of MenuItem to zero, and make the child component take the place it needs using the padding. This will make sure that children occupies all the insides of the parent.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of @Bhalahariharan V is good but does not take into account inputs that would have the value `all`. It would be thus better to add a property `data-button-all` to the `Select all` menu item.

Then, in the `handle change` function, check for this property to know if the select `all` button has been pressed or not.

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
const handleChange = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value.filter((val) => !!val);
  const isClickAll = !!(event.currentTarget as any).getAttribute('data-button-all');
  if (isClickAll) {
    setSelected(selected.length === options.length ? [] : options);
    return;
  }
  setSelected(value);
};


<Select
  multiple
  value={selected}
  onChange={handleChange}
  renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(", ")}
>
  <MenuItem data-button-all>
    <ListItemIcon>
      <Checkbox
        checked={options.length > 0 && selected.length === options.length}
        indeterminate={selected.length > 0 && selected.length < options.length}
      />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Select All" />
  </MenuItem>
  {options.map((option) => (
    <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <Checkbox checked={selected.indexOf(option) > -1} />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={option} />
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented, the accepted answer no longer works. It's still a good approach, but you have to take off the `multiple` option from the MUI `Select` component, and implement a `handleChange` on the `Select` that handles single items being added/removed from the list.

```
<Select
    className="search_items"
    hintText="Select Item"
    value={values}
    onChange={handleChange} 
>
    <MenuItem
      value="all"
    />
    {this.menuItems(values)}
 </SelectField>
```

```
const handleChange = selection => {
    if (selection === "all") {
      if (selected.length === options.length) {
        setSelected([]);
      } else {
        setSelected(options);
      }
    } else {
      let newSelected;
      if (selected.map(s => s.id).includes(selection.id)) {
        newSelected = selected.filter(s => s.id !== selection.id);
      } else {
        newSelected = [...selected, selection];
      }

      setSelected(newSelected);
    }
  };
```

The suggested answer is from before hooks, so I didn't totally update it, but you get the idea.